# Does $ax+by=cx+dy$ always imply $a=c$ and $b=d$?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Does $ax+by=cx+dy$ always imply $a=c$ and $b=d$? I can imagine that it does not always when $x$ and $y$ are functions of one another. Is there a rule or proof when this does hold and when it does not?

The way I would prove it is as follows:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y\\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
x & y\\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
c\\
d
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y\\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y\\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
x & y\\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
x & y\\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
c\\
d
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
c\\
d
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Am I overlooking something here?

Comment: What is $\begin{bmatrix} x & y\\ \end{bmatrix}^{-1}$? How do you invert a 1x2-matrix?

Comment: You are overlooking the fact that $[x\ y]^{-1}$ is not something that exists in any reasonable sense. The answer to your question is that it depends on what $x,y$ represent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the equality must hold for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, the answer is yes. This is easy to check... Taking $x=1$ and $y=0$ you have that $a=c$. Taking $x=0$ and $y=1$ you have that $b=d$.

**Edit:** Following MartinR's comment, I note that this condition can be weakened. If the equality is satisfied for two linearly independent vectors $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$ we must have $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Comment: It suffices that the equality holds for two linearly independent pairs $(x, y)$.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, you correct. The sufficient condition that I mention could be weakened.